# Startup Script to Run a Jar

Tags: bash, jar, startup, init.d

I have a fat jar file that that I want to control by running it as a service. I'm not a shell script expert, but took some inspiration from this blog post:

http://vertx.io/blog/vert-x-3-init-d-script/

I then modified it a bit to my needs as below:

```
#!/bin/bash

###
# chkconfig: 345 20 80
# description: Vert.x application service script
# processname: java
#
# Installation (CentOS):
# copy file to /etc/init.d
# chmod +x /etc/init.d/my-vertx-application
# chkconfig --add /etc/init.d/my-vertx-application
# chkconfig my-vertx-application on
#
# Installation (Ubuntu):
# copy file to /etc/init.d
# chmod +x /etc/init.d/my-vertx-application
# update-rc.d my-vertx-application defaults
#
#
# Usage: (as root)
# service my-vertx-application start
# service my-vertx-application stop
# service my-vertx-application status
#
###

# The directory in which your application is installed
APPLICATION_DIR="/Users/joe/Desktop/temp/tsdb-kafka-consumer"
# The fat jar containing your application
APPLICATION_JAR="tsdb-kafka-consumer-0.1.0-SNAPAHOT.jar"
# The application argument such as -Dfoo=bar ...
APPLICATION_ARGS="-Dlogback.configurationFile=prod-logger.xml -Dconfig.resource=application.integration.conf"
# The Java command to use to launch the application (must be java 8+)
#JAVA=/opt/java/java/bin/java

# ***********************************************
LOG_FILE="${APPLICATION_DIR}"
RUNNING_PID="${APPLICATION_DIR}"/RUNNING_PID
# ***********************************************

# colors
red='\e[0;31m'
green='\e[0;32m'
yellow='\e[0;33m'
reset='\e[0m'

echoRed() { echo -e "${red}$1${reset}"; }
echoGreen() { echo -e "${green}$1${reset}"; }
echoYellow() { echo -e "${yellow}$1${reset}"; }

# Check whether the application is running.
# The check is pretty simple: open a running pid file and check that the process
# is alive.
isrunning() {
  # Check for running app
  if [ -f "$RUNNING_PID" ]; then
    proc=$(cat $RUNNING_PID);
    if /bin/ps --pid $proc 1>&2 >/dev/null;
    then
      return 0
    fi
  fi
  return 1
}

start() {
  if isrunning; then
    echoYellow "The Vert.x application is already running"
    return 0
  fi

  pushd $APPLICATION_DIR > /dev/null
  nohup java $APPLICATION_ARGS -jar $APPLICATION_DIR/$APPLICATION_JAR > $LOG_FILE 2>&1 &
  echo $! > ${RUNNING_PID}
  popd > /dev/null

  if isrunning; then
    echoGreen "Kafka Consumer Application started"
    exit 0
  else
    echoRed "Kafka Consumer Application has not started - check log"
    exit 3
  fi
}

restart() {
  echo "Restarting Kafka Consumer Application"
  stop
  start
}

stop() {
  echoYellow "Stopping Kafka Consumer Application"
  if isrunning; then
    kill `cat $RUNNING_PID`
    rm $RUNNING_PID
  fi
}

status() {
  if isrunning; then
    echoGreen "Kafka Consumer Application is running"
  else
    echoRed "Kafka Consumer Application is either stopped or inaccessible"
  fi
}

case "$1" in
start)
    start
;;

status)
   status
   exit 0
;;

stop)
    if isrunning; then
    stop
    exit 0
    else
    echoRed "Application not running"
    exit 3
    fi
;;

restart)
    stop
    start
;;

*)
    echo "Usage: $0 {status|start|stop|restart}"
    exit 1
esac
```

When I tried running this script, I got the following error:

```
Joes-MacBook-Pro:script joe$ sh ./run.sh start
/bin/ps: illegal option -- -
usage: ps [-AaCcEefhjlMmrSTvwXx] [-O fmt | -o fmt] [-G gid[,gid...]]
          [-g grp[,grp...]] [-u [uid,uid...]]
          [-p pid[,pid...]] [-t tty[,tty...]] [-U user[,user...]]
       ps [-L]
./run.sh: line 73: /Users/joe/Desktop/temp/tsdb-kafka-consumer: Is a directory
/bin/ps: illegal option -- -
usage: ps [-AaCcEefhjlMmrSTvwXx] [-O fmt | -o fmt] [-G gid[,gid...]]
          [-g grp[,grp...]] [-u [uid,uid...]]
          [-p pid[,pid...]] [-t tty[,tty...]] [-U user[,user...]]
       ps [-L]
-e \e[0;31mKafka Consumer Application has not started - check log\e[0m
```

What is here the problem? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--pid` parameter is invalid on your OSX. You should change `ps --pid` on `isrunning()` to `ps -p`. This will work on Linux and OSX.

Comment: Ok Thanks! I got rid of the error. Now hitting the second error. What is wrong with this line: nohup java $APPLICATION_ARGS -jar ${APPLICATION_DIR/APPLICATION_JAR} > $LOG_FILE 2>&1 &

Comment: I'm getting an error at line 74 that says that it is a directory!

Comment: @sparkr I think you didn't mean `${APPLICATION_DIR/APPLICATION_JAR}`, but `${APPLICATION_DIR}/${APPLICATION_JAR}` instead?

Comment: Could it be because of the LOG_FILE?

Comment: I just want to specify the path where the log file should be written! How could I do this? I want this to be passed as a configuration parameter to my jar!

Comment: @sparkr run the script with `bash -x script params` in order to get more information. Perhaps some variable wasn't property initialized?

Comment: Yep, it was the log file that was causing the problem!

Comment: @sparkr Progress? Now I see, you need to define a filename to `LOG_FILE`, something like `LOG_FILE="${APPLICATION_DIR}/app.log"`

Comment: Yes, I figured that out! Thanks for the tip!